# How to read null delimited records in Groovy

Tags: groovy, record, separator

I'd like to read multiline records that are terminated by *null* records, like so :

```
<MARQUE><AR_CP>N3</AR_CP>
<Classif>07</Classif>
<RegnT>03</RegnT>\0<MARQUE><AR_CP>O1</AR_CP>
<AR_PC>M5W 1C8</AR_PC>
<Classif>07</Classif>
<RegnT>03</RegnT>\0<MARQUE><AR_CP>Q1</AR_CP>
<Classif>07</Classif>
<RegnT>03</RegnT>
...
```

I would like to read the file, one record at a time. In perl I would use the "input record separator" *$/* but I can't seem to find an equivalent in *Groovy*. Note that the file is too large to be slurped, and then simply split.

Is there an elegant way to do this in *Groovy*, or do I have to read byte per byte and "manually" break on '\0'?

Thank you!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could try using Scanner like this:

```
new File( '/path/to/file.txt' ).withReader { r ->
  new Scanner( r ).with { scanner ->
    scanner.useDelimiter( ~/\00/ )
    scanner.eachWithIndex { record, idx ->
      println "Record $idx ${record.split('\n').join()}"
    }
  }
}
```